# Count starts at 2

Tags: php

I don't know why but it disregards the first row of the table.
Please help:

```
    $row = 0;
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db");
    $query = "select * from user_accounts";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
      {
      echo $row['ID'] . " " . $row['Username'];
      echo "<br />";
      }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear in your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, you're declaring an un-needed variable (`$row = 0;`)and you're fetching twice, which you shouldn't do:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db");
$query = "select * from user_accounts";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo $row['ID'] . " " . $row['Username'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: Your solution fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help @Xkajl.

Answer (score 2):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
```

So, you fetch one, ignore it and then continue fetching

Comment: I didn't know sorry :(